# Rails 3: How can I make Paperclip-FFMPEG work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg, paperclip

I have Rails 3.0.3 with these gems:

- delayed_job 2.1.4
- delayed_paperclip 0.7.1
- paperclip 2.3.16
- paperclip-ffmpeg 0.7.0

(This combination is very specific. Some newer gems will not work with others.)

Here's my Video model:

```
class Video < Upload
  has_attached_file :file, :default_style => :view, :processors => [:ffmpeg],
    :url => '/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
    :path => ':rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style' \
      + '/:basename.:extension',
    :default_url => '/images/en/processing.png',
    :styles => {
      :mp4video => { :geometry => '520x390', :format => 'mp4',
        :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libx264',
          :vpre => 'ipod640', :b => '250k', :bt => '50k',
          :acodec => 'libfaac', :ab => '56k', :ac => 2 } } },
      :oggvideo => { :geometry => '520x390', :format => 'ogg',
        :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libtheora',
          :b => '250k', :bt => '50k', :acodec => 'libvorbis',
          :ab => '56k', :ac => 2 } } },
      :view => { :geometry => '520x390', :format => 'jpg', :time => 1 },
      :preview => { :geometry => '160x120', :format => 'jpg', :time => 1 }
    }
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => VIDEOTYPES,
    :if => Proc.new { |upload| upload.file.file? }
  process_in_background :file
end
```

When creating a new Video object with attachment, the original is saved, but no conversion will be done.  Even calling `Video.last.file.reprocess!` won't to a thing except returning `true`.  (Not sure what "true" means in this case as it didn't work.)

I tried hardcoding the path to ffmpeg in `Paperclip::options[:command_path]`.  I even tried deleting the paperclip-ffmpeg.rb file and replacing it with a blank file.  Really thinking I'd get an exception by doing the later, instead, I simply got "true" again.

It feels like the paperclip-ffmpeg.rb is being loaded, because it is required by `config/application.rb`, but nothing is called in it when trying to generate a thumbnail or convert a video.

Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any tutorial of how to user these 4 gems together (delayed_job, delayed_paperclip, paperclip, paperclip-ffmpeg), all I want to do is upload video and play it ! and I can't find a straight forward to do that till now!

Comment: Hi there, sorry to just notice your comment now. Sadly, I don't have a tutorial and I no longer have the code I made, but let me add it took quite some work. I remember having to convert the uploaded videos in three formats to make them work in all browsers. I wish I could be of more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I solved this problem myself, and it was caused by something I did.

I wrote my own script to import files and the database from an older app to Rails.  The files were in place, but someone I updated the database with the wrong file extensions (in this case, ".jpg" instead of ".MOV").

Paperclip will verify first to see if the original file exists before calling any processor, based on the file name stored in the database.  As it didn't, Paperclip just didn't do anything.  Once I had the data corrected, everything ran as expected.  (I had problems with FFMPEG, but that's a different issue.)

My apologies if I wasted anyone's time. Hope this can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar configuration for one of my project (but Rails 3.1.1) and everything works fine. I added paperclip-ffmpeg to my Gemfile not with config/application.rb. Maybe this helps!?

Comment: Turns out it was caused by a mistake of mine. Sorry about this. More details in my answer.